# Cannot find Telegram folder on Android 11

Tags: samsung, android-11, telegram

I have a Samsung A52S 5G with Android 11 installed on it. I have installed Telegram messaging app and have downloaded some files from groups.

In my old phone, I could find in the File Manager the Telegram folder with all the files downloaded through the app. Now, in this phone I cannot find the Telegram folder anywhere. This makes it difficult for managing the files especially the ones downloaded from groups.

Does anyone have any idea on where Telegram is saving the files in my phone?

Answer (score 4):

These are stored in `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.telegram.messenger/files/Telegram`.

You can't access them because of [scoped storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) introduced in Android 11,for improving data privacy. If your device is rooted, you can access using a rooted file explorer

Comment: My phone status is official so apparently is unrooted. Do you know any procedure to root it?

Comment: Sorry, no and you are better off searching XDA

Answer (score 2):

you can access scoped storage without having to root, use x-plore app. and just approve permissions when asked

Comment: Great, this really solved the issue