# Delete files downloaded from Telegram

Tags: android-11, telegram

As a follow up to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/243007/266354), consider a phone with Android 11 and telegram installed on it.

Consider that the user joins many groups, download some files from them and leaves some group, loosing track which groups he first joint and then left.

So now he has many useless files that he wants to delete to free some space. In old Android version, one could access the Telegram folder and check which files were in and eventually delete it. In android 11, from the answer to the question I've linked, this is not possible directly (or at least no as easily as before): how can one check which files are present on their Telegram folder/in his phone and eventually delete them?

Comment: As per the linked answer, I don't think you can selectively delete them without root. Though as per [the official Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage), they should be removed on uninstall.

Comment: Ok, how can I get root access or access that folder? Are there any apps that allow to do that?

Comment: See this: [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/44325), but note that unlocking the bootloader will wipe all the data.

Comment: My logic in suggesting uninstall followed by re-install is this - unlike WhatsApp where you need to backup, Telegram has everything in cloud. They wouldn't want to store data that the user doesn't need and take up cloud space //@AndrewT has given you the technical reason,thanks Andrew//It's far more simpler to do this rather than root, just for this

Comment: ok but you see that the procedure is suitable for once in a while. Constantly uninstalling an reinstalling Telegram might be annoying.

Comment: If cleaning up space is the prime reason, then root is the way to go but backup all data - the moment you unlock bootloader, all user data is lost